# Given the sequence $(x_n)$ is unbounded, show that there exist a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\lim(1/x_n)=0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Given the sequence $(x_n)$ is unbounded, show that there exist a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\lim(1/x_{n_k})=0$.

I guess I have to prove that $(x_{n_k})$ diverge, but I don't know how to carry on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Hint*: If $(x_n)$ is **unbounded**, then for each $N$ there are infinitely many $n$ with $|x_n| \ge N$. Now choose inductively $n_k$ such that $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ and $|x_{n_k}| > k$.