# If $(x_n)$ is unbounded, show that it contains a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $(1/x_{n_k})$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $(x_n)$ is unbounded, show that it contains a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\frac{1}{x_{n_k}}$ converges to $0$.

I have seen the inductive proof suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401033/given-the-sequence-x-n-is-unbounded-show-that-there-exist-a-subsequence-x). I am trying to go about a different way. We note that if $(y_n)$ is properly divergent, then $\frac{1}{y_n}$ converges to $0$. Hence, I want to make the following claim:

> ***Claim.*** Every unbounded sequence contains a properly divergent subsequence.

Here is my proposed proof for this:

If $(x_n)$ is unbounded, then it is divergent. If $x_n$ is properly divergent, then we are done, because $(x_n)$ is trivially a subsequence of itself. On the other hand, we consider the possibility that $(x_n)$ is not properly divergent meaning that it oscillates. I would like to prove that this osciallatory sequence must contain a subsequence which is properly divergent.

Any hints to continue the proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can prove that an unbounded above (below) sequence contains an increasing (decreasing) subsequence diverging to infinity (negative infinity). For the above case, you could construct a subsequence such that $x_{n_k}>x_{n_{k-1}}$ and $x_{n_k}>k$, hence properly divergent to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x_n)$ is unbounded positively. For each $i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ choose $n_i$ such that $x_{n_i}>i$. Then the subsequence $(x_{n_i})_i$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

I am presenting a different approach for this answer. Please correct me if am wrong. We know that "Every sequence of real numbers has a monotone subsequence." Therefore $x_{n}$ must have a monotone subsequence, say, $x_{n_{k}}$. Again, further, we know that " A monotone sequence of real numbers having a divergent subsequence is properly divergent." Now since $x_{n_{k}}$ itself is divergent then it must have a divergent subsequence and therefore it will be a properly divergent subsequence of $x_{n}$.