# Show that if $(x_n)$ is unbounded then $\exists$ subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ such that $lim (1/x_{n_{k}})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

A proof to the statement in title is already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933789/if-x-n-is-unbounded-show-that-it-contains-a-subsequence-x-n-k-such-th)  but I am trying to prove it by contradiction. The following is my proof: 
***Statement:*** If $(x_n)$ is unbounded then $\exists$ subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ such that $lim (1/x_{n_{k}})=0$ 
Suppose that for all subsequences of $x_n$, the implication is not true. 
$\therefore$   for any subsequence  ($x_{n_{k}}$),  ($\exists \epsilon\gt0$)($\forall K\in N$)($\exists n_k\ge K$): $|1/x_{n_k}|\gt \epsilon \Rightarrow |x_{n_k}|\lt \epsilon$                   `(A)`
(A) is true for all subsequences $\Rightarrow$ all subsequences of $x_n$ are bounded 
**Now my claim is:** All subsequences of $x_n$ are bounded $\implies$ $x_n$ is bounded 
 **Proof:** Let M= sup(set of bounds of all subsequences), if $x_n$ is unbounded then $(\exists N)(\forall n\ge N): |x_n|\gt M$. Now subsequence $(x_{m_n}): |x_{m_n}|\lt M$ which is a contradiction since $m_n\ge n$ 
$\therefore$ (A) is true for all subsequences $\Rightarrow$ all subsequences of $x_n$ are bounded $\implies$ $x_n$ is bounded, which is a contradiction. 
Is my proof correct? If wrong,please advise on how to prove the statement using contradiction.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you deduce that $(A)$ true for all subsequences $\implies$ all subsequences are bounded?

Comment: @awllower, since (A) is true for all subsequences. For any subsequence, $n_1<n_2<...$ can be chosen and $x_{n_k}$ will satisfy (A). So taking M=sup( set of all bounds of subsequences of $x_{n_k}$,  it is deduced that (A) true $\implies $ all subsequences are bounded. Is this wrong?

Comment: $(A)$ only means that there is $n_k>K$ such that $|x_{n_k}|<\varepsilon$, but it does not imply that the subsequence $x_{n_k}$ is bounded. Perhaps $x_{n_{k+1}}>\varepsilon$? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Taking K=1, (A) yields  $x_{n_1}$, K=2 yields $x_{n_2}$ & so on (all $x_{n_j} \lt 
 \epsilon$ by (A)). This gives rise to $(x_{n_k})$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, but that is only one subsequence which is bounded. How do you know **every** subsequence is bounded?

Comment: Ah, I see how $(A)$ being true for all subsequences implies every subsequence is bounded: if there is an unbounded subsequence, then $(A)$ is not true for that subsequence. Then the conclusion that the original sequence is bounded (the claim in the question body) is immediate: the original sequence is a subsequence of itself, so it is bounded.